# Can't find python console debugger in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I can't find the button or anyway to bring up a Debug Console. Neither of the suggestions here work - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-debug-console.html#

The python button isn't there and the tools option doesn't exist. I've attached a screen shot of what I'm seeing. I'm on PyCharm 2019.3

[image]

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint first in your code?

Comment: Yes I did. This is in a stopped state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred when using running an AWS Lambda function locally using the AWS Toolkit. In the lambda function debugger you can't get a console.